# How to authenticate a xml in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, authentication

I'm developing a webservice in asp.net and c#, which shows the content of the password protected XML file at [poinstreak.com](http://www.pointstreak.com/xml/GET/schedule_11200.xml). My problem is that I can't seem to get the authentication to work (I keep getting a 401 status). Any suggestions on how to solve this?

```
    protected void dataBind()
    {
        //Variables
        string xmlfile = "http://www.pointstreak.com/xml/GET/schedule_11200.xml";
        string xslfile = "/StyleSheet/XSLT/xslForGETMatches.xsl";

        //Credentials
        NetworkCredential myCred = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
        CredentialCache myCache = new CredentialCache();
        myCache.Add(new Uri(xmlfile), "Basic", myCred);

        //Set the credentials on the XmlUrlResolver object
        XmlUrlResolver resolver = new XmlUrlResolver();
        resolver.Credentials = myCache;

        //XSL Transformation
        XslCompiledTransform xslt = new XslCompiledTransform();
        xslt.Load(xslfile, XsltSettings.Default, resolver);
        StringBuilder outfile = new StringBuilder();
        XmlWriterSettings settings = xslt.OutputSettings.Clone(); 
        settings.CheckCharacters = false;
        xslt.Transform(xmlfile, XmlWriter.Create(outfile, settings));
        xmlToHtmlOutput.Text = outfile.ToString(); //An ASP Label
    }
```

Comment: XmlUrlResolver is used when you use the `document` function or similar within an XSLT. Is this the case within your XSLT? You can get the Xml directly via WebClient - see http://stackoverflow.com/a/9946968/1073107 for example, which you can then load into an XmlDocument and transform directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use HttpWebRequest to get the content of the xml and apply operation on it.

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
NetworkCredential credential = new NetworkCredential(username, password);

request.Credentials = credential;
request.PreAuthenticate = true;

WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
Stream Answer = response.GetResponseStream();

StreamReader _Answer = new StreamReader(Answer); 
string content = _Answer.ReadToEnd(); //the string of the whole xml
response.Close();
```